# PHP XML How to create Nested Node?

Tags: php, xml

I use php `DOMDocument` to create and save `XML` file.
here is my code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$document = $doc->createElement('DOCUMENT');
$document->nodeValue = '';
$doc->appendChild($document);

$order = $doc->createElement('ORDER');
$order->nodeValue = '';
$doc->appendChild($order);

$ele = $doc->createElement('Reportvariable1');
$ele->nodeValue = '';
$doc->appendChild($ele);

$ele = $doc->createElement('Reportvariable1');
$ele->nodeValue = '';
$doc->appendChild($ele);

$ele = $doc->createElement('Reportvariable1');
$ele->nodeValue = '';
$doc->appendChild($ele);

$ele = $doc->createElement('Reportvariable1');
$ele->nodeValue = '';
$doc->appendChild($ele);

$doc->appendChild($ele);
$doc->save('order_xml/Order_.xml');
```

its Output is simple like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DOCUMENT></DOCUMENT>
<ORDER></ORDER>
<Reportvariable1></Reportvariable1>
<Reportvariable1></Reportvariable1>
<Reportvariable1></Reportvariable1>
<Reportvariable1></Reportvariable1>
```

How do I create nested nodes like this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DOCUMENT>
    <ORDER>
       <Reportvariable1></Reportvariable1>
       <Reportvariable1></Reportvariable1>
       <Reportvariable1></Reportvariable1>
       <Reportvariable1></Reportvariable1>
   </ORDER>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use 3 steps to add a new node to the DOM.

1. Create the node using a method of the document object
2. Append the node using `appendChild()` to the parent (document or element)
3. Optionally set attributes on the element node.

`appendChild()` returns the node. So you can nest the `create*` call.

Don't set `DOMElement::$nodeValue`. It has a non standard behaviour and needs special escaping. Use the `DOMElement::$textContent` property. Or create a text node and append it.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$document = $dom->appendChild(
  $dom->createElement('DOCUMENT')
);
$order = $document->appendChild(
  $dom->createElement('ORDER')
);
// 3 nodes setting text content 
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  $order
    ->appendChild(
      $dom->createElement('Reportvariable1')
    )
    ->textContent = 'some text content' . $i;
}
// 3 nodes appending a text node
for ($i = 3; $i <= 6; $i++) {
  $order
    ->appendChild(
      $dom->createElement('Reportvariable1')
    )
    ->appendChild(
      $dom->createTextNode('some text content' . $i)
   );
}
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DOCUMENT>
  <ORDER>
    <Reportvariable1>some text content1</Reportvariable1>
    <Reportvariable1>some text content2</Reportvariable1>
    <Reportvariable1>some text content3</Reportvariable1>
    <Reportvariable1>some text content4</Reportvariable1>
    <Reportvariable1>some text content5</Reportvariable1>
    <Reportvariable1>some text content6</Reportvariable1>
  </ORDER>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:-

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
    $document = $doc->createElement('DOCUMENT');$document->nodeValue = '';$doc->appendChild($document);
    $order = $doc->createElement('ORDER');$order->nodeValue = '';$document->appendChild($order);

    $ele = $doc->createElement('Reportvariable1');$ele->nodeValue = '';$order->appendChild($ele);
    $ele = $doc->createElement('Reportvariable1');$ele->nodeValue = '';$order->appendChild($ele);
    $ele = $doc->createElement('Reportvariable1');$ele->nodeValue = '';$order->appendChild($ele);
    $ele = $doc->createElement('Reportvariable1');$ele->nodeValue = '';$order->appendChild($ele);
    $doc->save('order_xml/Order_.xml');
```

You will get the desired output

Comment: Works great.
but its in single line, how could I break line ?

Comment: Press enter after each ; and also mark my answer as correct at it works for you ....:)

Comment: Could you also mark my answer as a correct answer now?